# Dense Matrix Estimation

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, matrices

I have a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and I want to estimate it with a ***dense*** matrix $Y^{m\times n}$ such that $Y$ is still close to $X$ in some distance measure. Is this doable in a computationally efficient way? While the sparse estimation is commonly used, but all my efforts for a regularization based solution ended up in non-convex optimization.

Comment: Why not find a sparse neighbor and then add a matrix of all epsilons?

Comment: Theoretically you are right. But practically, I want the non-zero elements to be non-negligible, as well.

Comment: You should be more specific in your definition of "dense."